# How to reset autoincrement number with prefix of financial year in SQL Server and manually reset as you need

Tags: sql-server

I have a table with an autoincrement number with prefix. I want to reset the autoincrement number with prefix.

This is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
(
    [ID] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CaseNum]  AS (CONCAT(DATEPART(YEAR, GETDATE()), '-', RIGHT(CONCAT('000', [ID]), (3)))),
    [Key_DateTimeValue] [DATETIME] NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [CaseNum] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID] ASC)
                    WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                          IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                          ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

2019-75

After run query or function or procedure I want to be like this

2019-01 or 2019-00

Comment: `ID` is a primary key in that table. Resetting it would create duplicate keys, which is not allowed.

Comment: You are struggling here because what your trying to do violates 1NF. You are shoving two pieces of information into a single tuple. You don't want to do this to yourself. Not to mention that you would be violating the primary key of your table. I would suggest using a computed column instead. Or if you have to keep the value consistent when rows get deleted you could use a sequence and reset it at the beginning of the year. Of course that means you have to remember to reset it. No matter how you slice this it is brittle.

Answer (score 0):

To do this you have to empty the table first:

```
   DELETE FROM [dbo].[test]
```

or

```
   TRUNCATE TABLE [dbo].[test]
```

After doing so you can reseed the table with:

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[test]', RESEED, 1)
```

[More Info about DBCC @Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-checkident-transact-sql)

Comment: I doubt the OP wants to delete all their existing data here, otherwise that's what they would have asked.

Comment: no I can't delete all the existing data. just I want to reset autoIncrement number with prefix

Comment: If you want to start at 0 or 1, you have to make sure that these ids are free. It would be possible to update the existing data with a different id range (maybe > 1000) and start over at 1 with new rows.